# ViewDataDictionary Model Type Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am running an App with two main tables - TJob & TJobHistory. The TJobHistory table serves as an audit table to any changes made in the TJob table. I am trying to change my 'details' view so it will display the TJobHistory of the specific TJob entry that the user clicks on in the homepage. I am running into the following exception when I try to load the details page for any TJobs entry:

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Planner_App.Models.TJob', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'Planner_App.Models.TJobHistory'.

**Controller Code**

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            //Foreign key pulls//
            var TJob = await _context.TJob
                .Include(t => t.intCustomer)
                .Include(t => t.intDeveloper)
                .Include(t => t.intJobStatus)
                .Include(t => t.intJobType)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.intJobId == id);

            if (TJob == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(TJob);
        }
```

**View Code**

```
@model Planner_App.Models.TJobHistory
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}
```

I am still very new to MVC so I apologize if this isn't helpful - but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to fix you view model

```
@model Planner_App.Models.TJob
```

or if you really need to use TJobHistory and it is possible to convert TJob to TJobHistory you can try something like this

```
var model = await _context.TJob
                .Include(t => t.intCustomer)
                .Include(t => t.intDeveloper)
                .Include(t => t.intJobStatus)
                .Include(t => t.intJobType)
                .Where(m => m.intJobId == id)
                Select(i=> new TJobHistory
                 {
                   Id=i.Id,
                     ... TJobHistory properties
                  }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            if model == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(model);
```

or if TJobHistory is a copy of TJob maybe if would be enough  just replace _context.TJob  with _context.TJobHistory

```
var tJobHistory = await _context.TJobHistory
            ....
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What do you mean in the Select portion where you are saying Id=i.Id, TJobHistory properties? Could you give me an example?

Comment: @Parker I could if you could see TJob and TJobHistory classes. Pls post them asap.

Comment: Here is a temporary link to screenshots of my classes. https://postimg.cc/gallery/mHLx7YV